# Using c#/Xamarin, how can I call a class function?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm 12 hours into using Xamarin, and have a beginner blocker while working on a Xamarin / c# project for iOS 7.

This is how I though the view controller should call kickOff (but it doesnt work):

```
using iOS;
...
public void ViewDidLoad () {
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    kickOff ();
}
```

exampleClass.cs:

```
namespace iOS
{
public class foo
{
    public static void kickOff (){
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
     }
 }
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never point to the class foo. You need to tell it where to look for the method `kickOff()`

The following should work:

```
foo.kickOff();
```

**Note**

Your question doesn't say what doens't work, but I'm assuming it's a compiler error about kickOff not being a valid method

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - although I already tried this, your tip led me to diagnose a typo in my class name.